# Using Apache rewrite rules in .htaccess to remove .html causing a 500 error

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I have written a small website (4 pages, HTML only) and I want to remove the .html extension from the URL by putting some rewrite rules in my .htaccess file, I've Googled around and found several snippets similar to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

Both of the following URLs serve the same content (which I would expect)

```
https://example.io/contact
https://example.io/contact.html
```

However the following gives a 500 error:

```
https://example.io/contact/
```

This directory does not exist and if I remove the rewrite code mentioned above it will 404 instead which is what I would expect. Why is the code above causing a 500 error?

Even more interesting is that this will 500:

```
https://example.io/contact/blah
```

But this will 404:

```
https://example.io/contact123/blah
```

Neither contact/ or contact123/ exist as a directory but contact.html does exist and contact123.html does not.

Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

MrWhite has already given the correct answer but for anyone who is looking in future the Apache error logs look like this:

```
[Thu Oct 24 20:49:47.722210 2019] [core:error] [pid 13001:tid 139915446667008] [client 1.2.3.4:39006] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I had checked the logs and wasn't sure why it was happening but forgot to include this in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** A request for `/contact/` (or `/contact/blah`) results in a rewrite loop (500 Internal Server Error response) because `REQUEST_FILENAME` contains the mapped filesystem path; not the URL-path you are expecting.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
> ```

The "problem" is the use of `REQUEST_FILENAME` in the 2nd condition. The `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable contains the absolute filesystem path *after* the URL has been mapped to the filesystem. This is not necessarily the same as the URL-path - but this condition *assumes* that it is. When the URL-path contains whole path segments that do not map to the filesystem (as in `/contact/blah` or `/contact123/blah`) then the `REQUEST_FILENAME` is essentially "reduced" to the last path segment that maps to a directory, plus the "filename" (ie. `.../contact` and `.../contact123` respectively - the document root, ie. `/`, is the last matched directory in this example).

#### Request `/contact`

When you request `/contact` then the URL-path is `/contact` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `/path/to/document-root/contact` - so the `REQUEST_FILENAME` maps directly to the URL-path. The test condition `/path/to/document-root/contact.html` is successful and the request is rewritten to `contact.html`. All is good.

#### Request `/contact/` or `/contact/blah`

However, when you request `/contact/` then the URL-path is `/contact/`, but the `REQUEST_FILENAME` is again `/path/to/document-root/contact` (no slash suffix). The test condition is again successful (as above), but the request is rewritten to `contact/.html` (since `.html` is appended to the *captured* URL-path, ie. `$1.html`). Processing loops, `REQUEST_FILENAME` evaluates to the same as before (the condition is again successful) and the request is rewritten a 2nd time to `contact/.html.html`. Etc, etc, resulting in a rewrite loop which eventually reaches an internal limit (default 10) when it "breaks" and the server responds with a 500 Internal Server Error.

#### Request `/contact123/blah`

`/contact123/blah`, on the other hand, results in a 404 because the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable becomes `/path/to/document-root/contact123` and `/path/to/document-root/contact123.html` does not exist, so no rewrite occurs in the first place.

## Solution

To "fix" this behaviour we need to make sure we are testing the same file/URL-path that we are ultimately rewriting to.

We can do this by constructing the absolute filename (to test) by concatenating the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `REQUEST_URI` server variables (or `$1` backreference), which contains the root-relative URL-path. (Note that `REQUEST_URI` includes the slash prefix, whereas the `$1` backreference does not.)

For example:

```
# Rewrite request to append ".html" extension to URL
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [L]
```

Now, the test condition is testing the same filesystem path that the request will be rewritten to (if successful).

There is no need to check that the request does not map to a directory *and* that it does map to a file (when appending the `.html` extension), unless you also have directories with the same name as the file basename (eg. `basename.html` and `basename/`). But if that is the case then one or other is not going to be inaccessible anyway, so the situation is best avoided.

A request for `/contact/`, `/contact/blah` or `/contact123/blah` all now result in a 404 as expected.

Note that there's no need to backslash escape the literal dot in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* since this is not a regex.

Minor points... the `^` and `$` anchors on `^(.*)$` (and `^(.+)$`) are unnecessary since the `*` (and `+`) quantifier is greedy by default (although some users do still seem to like them for *readability*?). You should also include the `L` (`last`) flag on the `RewriteRule`. Whilst this is not necessary if this is the only (or last) rule in the `.htaccess` file, if you should add more rules later then it probably is (and having to remember to modify existing rules in this way is prone to error).

With the use of the `$1` backreference in the `RewriteCond` directive, this does assume that the `.htaccess` file is in the document root, otherwise, the filesystem check as written will be incorrect. If the `.htaccess` file is located in a subdirectory then change the `RewriteCond` directive to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [L]
```

---

#### Optimisation

You could avoid unnecessarily checking all requests that already contain a file extension (ie. all your static resources) by restricting the regex to URLs that do not contain what looks-like a file extension. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: You sir are my everything!! Thanks :) really appreciate the explanation as well as the code.