# What does %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.ext mean? Why the extra .ext ending?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

The `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` contains a string like this:

```
/web/webroot/index.php
```

I see a lot of people recommend testing if a file exists and has a .php extension like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

Isn't the `.php` after `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` redundant? The variable should already contain the `.php`, right?

Seems like adding `.php` after `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` would make the TestString check add an extra .php, like this:

```
/web/webroot/index.php.php
```

I'm missing something simple, I'm sure of it, but I just don't know what it is.

The context is this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*?\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't the `.php` after `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` redundant? The variable should already contain the `.php`, right?

Well, yes and no, it depends what you are trying to do.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
> ```

This rule allows you to request extensionless URLs. eg. `/index` or `/foo` and this internally rewrites the request to `/index.php` and `/foo.php` respectively.

In this instance, `REQUEST_FILENAME` is a string of the form `/web/webroot/index`. So, it's testing that `/web/webroot/index.php` exists before rewriting to the same. If you were to request `/index.php` then the *condition* fails and no rewrite occurs (which is correct).

However, this rule isn't strictly correct and could cause a rewrite-loop under certain conditions. See the following related question:

- [Using Apache rewrite rules in .htaccess to remove .html causing a 500 error](https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error)

Comment: I see you know your stuff. I'll stare at this for a few more hours until I figure it out. I think you're saying the variable is modified by appending the `.ext`, but I can't find this behavior documented anywhere except on SE forums. EDIT: Yeah, okay, I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff The variable itself (ie. `REQUEST_FILENAME`) isn't modified, just the _TestString_ (first argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) - as you state in the question. It's basically testing whether the requested URL + `.php` exists as a physical file. Although, `REQUEST_FILENAME` isn't strictly the correct variable to use here (although works in _most_ cases), as mentioned in the linked question. (`REQUEST_FILENAME` is the "file" that the requested URL maps to.)

Comment: Well since I, of course, want to use strictly the correct variables in my code, is this the one: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f`?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, and change the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ string accordingly. ie. `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]`

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much!

Comment: @Jeff The regex `!\.\w{2,4}$` excludes all requests that already include what _looks like_ a file extension. It's just an optimisation, to prevent all static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc) from being unnecessarily tested to see if `image.jpg.php` exists etc. (filesystem checks are relatively expensive). Files don't _normally_ have two file extensions like `exists.qqq.php`, so wouldn't normally be a problem. But it is just an optimisation so is safe to remove. You could achieve a similar optimisation by excluding the subdirectory where all your static assets are stored.

Comment: Good stuff. Doesn't the `RewriteCond` line before the exclusion regex already exclude all those extra tests to the other static resources (besides .html files)?

Comment: @Jeff The `RewriteRule` directive is processed first. Only when the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches are the preceding _conditions_ processed. If the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is not successful then the entire rule is skipped and processing continues...

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. Thanks again!